# Flutter Build Error when using iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, flutter

Since updating my macOS and Xcode, my flutter build is not working for my iOS Simulator. It is showing me the following error:

Error (Xcode): "Runner" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning
profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
/Users/mustafa/Desktop/flutter_starter/ios/Runner.xcodeproj

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
No Provisioning Profile was found for your project's Bundle Identifier or your
device. You can create a new Provisioning Profile for your project in Xcode for
your team by:
1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
in the project settings
3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected under Signing & Capabilities >
Team.
You may need to:
- Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
- Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
- Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
- Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
4- Build or run your project again

It's also possible that a previously installed app with the same Bundle
Identifier was signed with a different certificate.

For more information, please visit:
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices

Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing

Even though I've tried to use it for debugging purposes to see how my application looks like and to see what errors are there.

I'm currently Software versions i'm currently using are:

macOS Sonoma 14.0
Xcode 15
Flutter 3.16.0-6.0.pre.12

Answer (score 0):

I have a few ideas To fix the error, follow these steps and I hope help you:

- Open the 'projectName.xcodeproj' in Xcode.
- Select the Runner project in the navigator, then the Runner target in
  the project settings.
- Under the Signing & Capabilities tab, make sure a Valid Development Team is
  selected.

> If you don't have a provisioning profile for your app, click the
> Create Provisioning Profile.

Once you have a provisioning profile selected, click the Run button to build and run your app on the simulator.

If you're still getting the error after following these steps, it's possible that a previously installed app with the same Bundle Identifier was signed with a different certificate. To fix this, you can try deleting the old app from your simulator before running your new app.

**Make sure that your project's Bundle Identifier is unique.**

[image: please check iOS simulator, a valid Team, and unique Bundle Identifier]

Please ensure you have selected the iOS simulator, a valid Team, and a unique Bundle Identifier.

Comment: Is it not possible to do this without having a signing certificate as there seems to be an error when i'm making a developer account because on the previous update I was able to use iOS Simulator without needing a certificate